# Data Workflow - Trouble aggregating 50 million rows in R?

Tags: r, database, apache-spark-sql

The data set begins as 12 monthly csv files. Each file is loaded into R to work with. One step is to find all combinations of a certain factor group which results in 4 million rows. I have 16gb RAM on my computer, which with other tasks, is not enough to store all 12x4million rows. The end goal is to group by and summarize the 50 million rows. Not sure how to do this, hoping for suggestions.

Some thoughts/ideas that I’ve had: 
Write each 4 million row dataset to a database to then do the aggregation? I’ve had trouble with RODBC being prohibitively slow for this size. Or a local database using SQLite? What about SparklyR?

Comment: how many columns (just to give a rough idea) - a) in the original CSVs and b) that you need for the analysis.

Comment: 5 columns are needed for the analysis and the csvs begin as 3 columns

Comment: are you sure you can't do it all in RAM?  I can simulate data like that in R and it's only 1GB.  But assuming you have your reasons - make a database, bulk load it straight from CSV into the database, and do the grouping and summarizing with SQL.  If you must go through R, use data.table fread to read in, fwrite to read it out, and bulk load into the database (rather than try from ODBC).